# "on the Dean's list" or "on Dean's list"?

Tags: definite-article, terminology

When I want to say on my resume that I was mentioned on that list, should I say

> Was mentioned on the Dean's list several times.

or

> Was mentioned on Dean's list several times.

?

I think that the first is better but [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/) (a grammar-checking application) gave an error when I wrote it:

> It is unlikely that your sentence needs both the article the and the determiner Dean's. Consider deleting the article.

Comment: I remain skeptical of automated grammar-checkers in general, but according to their website, Grammarly is supposed to provide explanations when it flags a suspicious word or construction. Why does Grammarly prefer the second?

Comment: +1. Here is what Grammarly says: "It is unlikely that your sentence needs both the article the and the determiner Dean's. Consider deleting the article."

Comment: Thanks. In that case, @DoWhileNot 's explanation seems to be correct, and I would retain the article. That said, in a U.S. context, this strikes me as unnecessarily wordy; *Dean's List* on its own would be self-explanatory, as in, *Rice University, AB Philosophy, Cum Laude, Dean's List 5 semesters* or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On the Dean's list" is correct.  You probably got the error from Grammarly because of the confusion between "Dean" the title and "Dean" the name.

If I was on Dean's list, then I would be on a list made by some guy named Dean.

If I was on the Dean's list, then I'd be on a list of someone who's title was, "The Dean."